# How can I set up relation between two tables and make a working query?

Tags: next.js, prisma, prisma2

This is my DB schema:

```
model Logistics {
  logisticsid     String   @id
  logistics_store Int
  logistics_date  DateTime
  Stores          Stores?  @relation(fields: [logistics_store], references: [storeid])
}

model Stores {
  storeid   Int         @id
  ka        Int
  country   String
  name      String
  city      String
  address   String
  kgrp_name String
  password  String
  cxw       Int
  cx        Int
  plz       Int
  Logistics Logistics[]
}
```

And this is my API where I query the DB and send the results back to the client:

```
export default async function handle(req, res) {
  await runMiddleware(req, res, cors);
  try {
    const logistics = await prisma.logistics.findMany({
      where: { logistics_store: storeid },
      include: { Stores }
    });
    res.json(logistics);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to get the full `Logistics` table with 3 colums, and get the `Stores` where `logistics_store = storeid`.

Comment: The query looks fine with maybe one remark that `include: { Stores }` should be `include: { Stores: true }`. I wonder if that is the problem.

Is there an error? What's the result of the query?